# Particles render in viewport, but not in final

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles

I have a super simple Particle system. I am instancing a sphere (Render->Object->DupliObject->Sphere) with a white emission material.
When I set the viewport to render everything shows up fine, when I hit F12 nothing shows....
WHY?

I don't have any postprocessing enabled in the rendersettings, and I tried to cache the particles, but nothing so far...
Any ideas?

[Here is a simplified scene that shows that behaviour](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33752)

I could create a new system in a fresh scene, and append it into my main scene. So the problem is not related to the rendersettings.

Comment: There are many possible causes, could you upload your .blend file to [**Pasteall.org/blend**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) for us to look at?

Comment: I added the link to a samplescene to the mainpost.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the particle emitter is hidden in the render:

[image]

Particles inherit the object level properties of the emitter, so hiding the emitter object will hide the particles.

To exclude the emitter from the render without hiding the particles, disable *Emitter* in *Particle settings > Render*:

[image]

*This is already disabled in your file*.

To hide the emitter in the viewport without hiding particles, see [Is it possible to hide particle emitters in the viewport without hiding particles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3539/599).

Comment: This is so embarrassing.... I was sure I checked that more than once. Sorry for wasting your time! Thanks! ...But why doesn't this affect the viewport render?

Comment: @knekke Viewport render still uses viewport settings. I guess the rational was to be consistent, and not to use potentially really slow settings (lots of subdivisions, many hair particles, etc.) in the real-time render.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this answer is a bit late but I need to share that when making a fireball scene I didn't add a material to my emitter. This was the deciding factor in me seeing my Particles and not seeing them.

I believe you can still make it so that the emitter isn't seen by clicking the camera button in your outliner with the emitter selected.

[image: Here's the fireball with out any particles. They appeared however after giving a material to my emitter] [image: The second image has the emitter with a material]

Answer (score 0):

Your parent object (the particle) must also be on the same layer as the emitter.